# How do I restore the VS Code Debug Auto-Save feature?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am unsure of exactly how and when this happened, but close to the latest update to VS Code 1.70.1, the auto-saving feature associated with (python) the debugging console "restart" or "start" is not working any longer, i.e., if you modify any file in the project, they do not get saved when you click restart on the console. It was a very handy and saved time. Could you please suggest how to restore it?

Answer (score 3):

VS Code have now released 1.70.2, this should solve your problem. I'm running in the most recent update, and autosave is a tickable option in the File Drop Down Menu for me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is not quite the auto-save that saves at some time intervals, yet thanks to your note I have updated to 1.70.2, and the degub-auto-save is back on!